# problems to calculate $\int_\gamma \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2}dz$

Tags: complex-integration

Some ideas to may begin to calculate $\int_\gamma \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2}dz$?(where $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{C}$ def by $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$). Trying by definition I obtain an expression like $e^{ie^{it}}$ which is weird.

Comment: Use the Residue theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem

Comment: @mfl thanks! I'm going to read about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the function $$f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2}$$ is analytic on all $\mathbb{C}/{0}$. The function has a *pole* of order two in $0$. The contour you're integrating on contains the pole of the function so you can use the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) to evaluate your integral: $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2} = 2\pi i\operatorname{Res}(f(z),0)\tag1$$

Now it's just a matter to evaluate your resiude. Being $0$ a pole of order $2$ we can evaluate it in the following manner $$\operatorname{Res}(f(z),0) = \lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{d}{dz}\left(z^2\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2}\right) = \lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{d}{dz}\left(e^{iz}\right) = \lim_{z\rightarrow 0}(ie^{iz}) = i$$

Or we could evaluate it by the Laurent series around $0$ of the function, which can be easily found by the Taylor series of $e^{iz}$ $$e^{iz} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(iz)^n}{n!} = 1+iz-\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{iz^3}{6}+O(z^4)$$ dividing it by $z^2$ we get the Laurent series of $f(z)$ $$\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty i^n\frac{z^{n-2}}{n!} = \frac{1}{z^2}+\color{red}{i}\frac{1}{z}-{1\over 2}-\cdots$$
the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ coloured coefficient *is the residue* at $z=0$

In both cases we found out that the residue evaluates to $i$ so plugging it back into $(1)$ we get the value of the integral $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2} = 2\pi i\operatorname{Res}(f(z),0) =  2\pi i\color{red}{i} = -2\pi$$

Comment: Most clear impossible. Thanks Davide ;)!

Comment: It's a real pleasure! I'm happy that helped

Comment: Just remember to accept the answer when you can so that other MSE users will know that you've got the answer to what you wanted to no! It also gives the user that answered more points for the response!

Comment: true, I always forget to do it :P

Answer (score 0):

We denote $f(z)=\dfrac{e^{iz}}{z^2}.$ Using the Residue theorem we get

$$\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz=2\pi i Res(f,0)$$ since the only singularity of $f$ is a pole of order $2$ at $0$ (which lies in the interior of $\gamma$).

Now

$$f(z)=\dfrac{1+iz-\dfrac{z^2}{2}+o(z^2)}{z^2}=\dfrac{1}{z^2}+\dfrac{\color{red}{i}}{z}-\dfrac 12+o(1)$$ from where

$$Res(f,0)=i.$$

So, we have

$$\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz=2\pi i Res(f,0)=-2\pi.$$